# sharing session, server to router

Tags: express

i want share the session to router from server

**my server:**

```
var routesEvaluacion = require('./routes/evaluacion');
app.use('/evaluacion', routesEvaluacion);
...
app.use(session({
    secret: 'administrador',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.post('/consultas', function (req, res) {

    if (req.body.nombre === "student" && req.body.pass === "student") {
        req.session.nombre = 'student';
        res.redirect('/listaEvaluaciones');
    }

});
```

**i need the session on router**(different files server and router)

```
router.get('/autenticacion/:id',function (req, res) {
 //  **req.session.nombre**
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the session in your router as well, you need to place the middleware call, ie, `app.use(session...)` before you use the router. This is because the request and response objects flow through the middleware in the order the middleware were placed. For your case just change the code to:

```
var routesEvaluacion = require('./routes/evaluacion');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'administrador',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use('/evaluacion', routesEvaluacion);
...

app.post('/consultas', function (req, res) {

    if (req.body.nombre === "student" && req.body.pass === "student") {
        req.session.nombre = 'student';
        res.redirect('/listaEvaluaciones');
    }

});
```

Now you'd be able to access the req.session object in your routes in `evaluacion` file as well.